# Code before while(1) does not run

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have code like this below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("hello");

    while(1){
        // whatever here
    }
}
```

and the question is: why the first instruction is skipped? It runs only the loop, hello is never printed. I compiled it with gcc and g++ with the same result.

Comment: Good question. Complete with full enough source code and a easily understandable question. (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, your code does run, only `stdout` is not flushed, but buffered.

Use `fflush(stdout)` after `printf("hello")`, this forces stdout to be printed.

And, as @Bathsheba pointed out, also a newline character (`"\n"`) within the `printf` forces it to flush, which is explained [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin).

Answer (score 5):

It **does** run, it's just that the output buffer is not *flushed* before your `while`.

Use `printf("hello\n");` instead. The newline character will flush the buffer so writing the output immediately to your console.